# Execution Plan in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, prepared-statement

I have a stored procedure in my database. As per my knowledge it's pre-compiled subroutine.

**Question 1**: If I execute following queries from Hibernate, will database create a separate execution plan for each query? In which case SQL Server update/change stored procedure Execution Plan?

```
EXECUTE myProcedure 'vicky.thakor', 'Routine Check Up'
```

and

```
EXECUTE myProcedure 'chirag.thakor', 'Routine Check Up'
```

**Question 2**: This is bit of programming question but you guys may explain me bit of it. In Java there is something called `PreparedStatement`. `PreparedStatement` is similar to pre-compiled query.

`PreparedStatement` generates query like following and put value in place of `?`.

```
SELECT * FROM user_master WHERE user_name = ?
```

But database will receive the final query like

```
SELECT * FROM user_master WHERE user_name = 'vicky.thakor'
```

then how database help to get best performance when using `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: stored procedures in SQL Server are **NOT** "pre-compiled" or anything.

Just like an ad-hoc SQL query, a stored procedure is analyzed when it's first used, an execution plan is determined and cached.

When the stored procedure is executed again, then that pre-existing execution plan is reused. Same applies to a properly parametrized SQL ad-hoc query.

The point is: as long as the **actual** SQL statement is ***IDENTICAL*** (down to the last comma or space), then a possibly pre-existing, cached execution plan is reused and the whole step of determining an execution plan can be skipped. If the SQL statement text varies - even by a single space - the whole process of analyzing and coming up with an execution plan for that query is run again.

I don't know about how Java handles it's prepared statements, but in C# using ADO.NET, when you run a query something like

```
SELECT * FROM user_master WHERE user_name = @userName
```

and you supply a value for `@userName` (e.g. 'vicky.thakor'), then the SQL Server will ***NOT*** received what you seem to think it will receive - the parameter is ***NOT*** replaced in the query text - instead, SQL Server will execute this as

```
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt, N'@userName', @userName = 'vicki.thakor'
```

SQL Server will receive a **parametrized query** and a list of parameters and their values.

Therefore, if you call this same query again, with a different value for `@userName`, the actual SQL statement text is **identical** and the cached execution plan is reused - only the value of the parameter has changed.

Comment: +1 It is important to note that since the same plan can be re-used for different parameters, the plan that's cached using one parameter value may not be optimal for another. Think about `LastName = N'Smith'` vs. `LastName = N'Quixote'`. If you have cases where you expect different parameter values to deserve different plan shapes, there are several ways you can try to defeat this problem, e.g. `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` or `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: absolutely - one of the trickier aspects of plan caching ...